# how to use pandas.assign with lambda and if condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, assign

can anyone please tell me what's the problem in the line code above

```
out_inf=q25-1.5*iqr
out_sup=q75+1.5*iqr

df=df.assign(label=1 if ((df'std']<out_inf) is True) | ((df['std']>out_sup) is True) else 0)
```

my new column have only 0 which is not correct 
normally i gotta have them both because I've tried this with a simple for{ if else } but it took too long to be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a better approach:

```
df['label']=((df['std']<out_inf)|(df['std']>out_sup)).astype(int)
```

Or for any other if,else conditions use [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
m=(df['std']<out_inf)|(df['std']>out_sup)
df['label']=np.where(m,1,0)
```

Conditions like `(df['std']<out_inf)` will return a boolean output already, so we are avoiding any further comparison.